# Transform XML with XSL from Get to AddChange

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML with XSL but I don't know what it's wrong. Fields in the destination XML are named different and the structure is also a little different. Also..If I make a get request and i receive the xml below it is possible to transform it in an xml with AddChange action?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RegisterSearch TotalResults="149">
<SearchResults>
  <Document DocumentId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
     <DocumentNumber>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</DocumentNumber>
     <Title>Test Title</Title>
  </Document>
</SearchResults>
</RegisterSearch>
```

My XSL file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="SearchResults"/>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="SearchResults">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="Document">

        <Ext_DB_STG class="R"> 

            <xsl:apply-templates select="mro:SITEID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mro:TASKID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mro:WONUM"/>

        </Ext_DB_STG>

 </xsl:template> 
 <!-- <xsl:template match="WORKORDER.> --> 

<xsl:template match="mro:SITEID">
 <DocumentId><xsl:value-of select="."/></DocumentId>
 </xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="mro:TASKID">
 <DocumentNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></DocumentNumber>
 </xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="mro:WONUM">
     <Title><xsl:value-of select="."/></Title>
    </xsl:template> 

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong?

The result XML i want to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MXITEMIN xmlns="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration" language="EN">
    <Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     operation="Notify" event="1">
        <SenderID type="MAXIMO" majorversion="6" minorversion="0" build="02" dbbuild="V600-76">EXTSYS1</SenderID>
        <CreationDateTime>2005-08-15T14:28:06-05:00</CreationDateTime>
        <RecipientID>MX</RecipientID>
        <MessageID>11241304878859947</MessageID>
    </Header>
    <Content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MXITEM>
            <ITEM action="AddChange">
                <SITEID>001TEST</SITEID>
                <TASKID>test item</TASKID>
                <WONUM>1</WONUM>

            </ITEM>
        </MXITEM>
    </Content>
</MXITEMIN>
```

Comment: Your XSL namespace is wrong. It should be `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`. Also, how would look like your desired outcome XML?

Comment: @zx485 see my edit please

Comment: @zx485 I've also did the change suggested by you and now I get the next error: Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.System does not support the specified encoding. Error processing resource

Comment: That's weird, because it is the correct namespace. However, it seems that half of your XSLT is supposed to work in the opposite direction: from output to input.

Comment: well, please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm trying to figure it out. What I want to do is a request that will return me a result list..and i want to process that result list as an AddChange action on my app. So I need to add an XSL transformation in order to receive the response in the format I need.

Comment: @zx485 it is possible to do that xml ?

Comment: As I wrote above: half of your XSLT points in one direction and the other half in the other. Further, I do not know what an "AddChange" or a "Get" action is. And in what App?

Comment: I'm just giving it a try and create an _input XML_ to _desired XML_ transformation as good as possible. It may take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT-1.0 code to transform some parts of the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mro="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="MXITEMIN" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
            <xsl:attribute name="language">EN</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="RegisterSearch/SearchResults"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SearchResults">
        <xsl:element name="Header" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
            <xsl:attribute name="operation">Notify</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="event">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="SenderID" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">MAXIMO</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="majorversion">6</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="minorversion">0</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="build">02</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="dbbuild">V600-76</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="CreationDateTime" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">2005-08-15T14:28:06-05:00</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="RecipientID" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">MX</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="MessageID" namespace="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">11241304878859947</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Document">
        <Content xmlns="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
            <MXITEM>
                <ITEM action="AddChange">
                    <SITEID><xsl:value-of select="..."/></SITEID>
                    <TASKID><xsl:value-of select="..."/></TASKID>
                    <WONUM><xsl:value-of select="..."/></WONUM>
                </ITEM>
            </MXITEM>
        </Content>
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MXITEMIN xmlns="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration" language="EN">
  <Header operation="Notify" event="1">
    <SenderID type="MAXIMO" majorversion="6" minorversion="0" build="02" dbbuild="V600-76"/>
    <CreationDateTime>2005-08-15T14:28:06-05:00</CreationDateTime>
    <RecipientID>MX</RecipientID>
    <MessageID>11241304878859947</MessageID>
  </Header>
  <Content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mro="http://www.mro.com/mx/integration">
    <MXITEM>
      <ITEM action="AddChange">
        <SITEID/>
        <TASKID/>
        <WONUM/>
      </ITEM>
    </MXITEM>
  </Content>
</MXITEMIN>
```

So you have to adjust the `xsl:value-of` "..." expressions to select the values you want (which are not present in the input XML). The namespaces are mostly correct, but I guess that you have to adjust them after all.

Comment: Wow it works! I have 2 more questions..It takes the other 2 values but not the one for Document Documentid. how should I refer to that component? I want after taking it to use the for each synthax..cause the xml will contain more line. This is the information i want to use <Document DocumentId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">  and i modified what you've sent me with this in order to take the fields from xml received<SITEID><xsl:value-of select="DocumentId"/></SITEID>
                    <TASKID><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></TASKID>
                    <WONUM><xsl:value-of select="DocumentNumber"/></WONUM>

Comment: I found the answer..it is  <SITEID> <xsl:value-of select="./@DocumentId"/></SITEID> :) thank you a lot again!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!